# Fundamental Period of Harmonic Complex Exponentials

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform, discrete-time

If I have a complex exponential in the discrete time domain $e^{j\Omega n}$ where $\Omega =\frac {2\pi k}{N}$.I understand that the signal is periodic as k varies but what I'm not able to grasp is that these harmonically related signals though periodic have different fundamental period. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Help you with what? Help you understand why they have different fundamental periods? Well, examine some examples to see! Notice that the fraction $k/N$ can be simplified depending on the value of $k$...

Comment: help me understand why the fundamental period is is not the same as the period N for all the harmonic complex exponentials?

Comment: What I understand is that the fundamental period is the period of the first harmonic...so the complex exponential repeat after N intervals...so shouldn't the fundamental period be same for all the harmonic complex exponential signals? For examples $e^{j\Omega kn}$ and $e^{j2\Omega kn}$ should have the same period and fundamental period that is N

Comment: What if $k=N$? Then there is no denominator. There is no $N$ anymore, because it got cancelled out. And you get a constant function! That still has period $N$, but fundamental period $1$ now. Or for instance if $N=4$ and $k=1$ we're talking about the function $i^n$ which has fundamental period $4$, but if $k=2$ then we're talking about the function $(-1)^n$ which has fundamental period $2$. In general the denominator will no longer be $N$ if $k$ shares factors with $N$ because there is cancellation.

Comment: The same concept occurs with continuous functions. For instance, $\sin t$ and $\cos x$ have fundamental period $2\pi$, but if you "speed them up" to $\sin 2t$ and $\cos2t$ the functions go through the range twice as fast, so it takes them "half as long" to repeat, i.e. the fundamental period is halved - indeed the graphs themselves get squeezed horizontally by a factor of $2$ like an accordion. (Doing this for a discrete time domain, the "sped up" function may have smaller range, but the same idea applies.)

Comment: So what I understand is that fundamental period and the period are same only for the first harmonic and the fundamental period is basically the $\frac{N}{k}$ and hence would be different for higher harmonics.

Comment: In this context it doesn't make sense to say "*the* period," it only makes sense to say "*a* period." Every integer multiple of the fundamental period is a period. For instance, U.S. elections have a fundamental period of $4$ years, but $8$ and $20$ and every other multiple of $4$ is also a period. (Of course some sources will use the term "period" to mean "fundamental period," but these are distinct concepts in any context that bothers to use the term "fundamental.") Anyway, the fundamental period in your discrete time example will be $N/d$ in general, where $d=\gcd(k,N)$.

Comment: Thank you @runway44!